# Сокращение: точка после гласной

Tags: сокращения

Как мы знаем, все сокращения обязательно должны заканчиваться на согласную. И именно после согласной ставится точка. Например, "стр. 23" - то есть, "страница 23". Но есть общепринятое сокращение "о.", когда речь идет о священнослужителе, то есть, "отец такой-то". Например, "священник о. Вячеслав". Как же тут быть? Выходит, что после гласной ставится точка, и само сокращение идет на гласную букву.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для некоторых слов допускается сокращение до первой буквы, как согласной, так и гласной: о. - отец, а также остров, и. о. - исполняющий обязанности, Ф. И. О. и др. Такие случаи проверяются по ГОСТу и словарям сокращений.